# Git diff showing changes at the beginning of text file

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, winmerge

I am trying to compare two text files using GIT and WinMerge. While WinMerge is correctly presenting me changes (i have one line changed between files), the git diff command is detecting some "weird" character at the beginning of the text file, which is normally not present. This results in WinMerge reporting 1 line change, while git diff reporting 2 lines changed. I suspect it has to do with different encoding of both files (?) - how can I prevent git from detecting this "additional" change?

Apologies for low quality images - I had to obfuscate them.

[image: GIT diff]
[image: WinMerge diff]

Comment: looks like a unicode BOM sequence

Comment: It seems so @LeGEC. But I do not know how to make git diff to ignore it, I keep googling but can't find any easy way out. It seems weird to me that winmerge could do this better and easier than git - I find it difficult to believe git diff is more limited here.

Comment: I agree with @LeGEC although it seems odd for the BOM to be shown as a blobby hard-to-see (reverse video?) blank: byte order marks are not supposed to be displayed as whitespace as they're zero-width. There's no point in storing a byte order mark in a UTF-8 file as UTF-8 has no byte order issues in the first place (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) so you should just convince whatever's putting it in to stop putting it in.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `git diff` is correct here: if one version has the BOM and the other doesn't, then although the semantics of the file is identical, the contents are not, so it should flag that difference: you'll have to deal with it in case of merge or conflict resolution, etc.

Comment: Now, I just tested in a PowerShell window, and when I do a `git diff` where the only difference is a BOM, I get a plain space displayed where that BOM is, not the character you show. I recommend inspecting that file with a binary viewer to confirm what that character really is. I bet it's something you actually want to remove, and not ignore, which brings me back to claiming `git diff` is doing the right thing by telling you it's there.

Comment: @joanis I do not say that it's invalid - of course files are different and it is presented like so. What I do say is WinMerge can be set up to ignore such differences with a simple setting change, whereas git diff, which I would expect to be a lot more advanced, seem to not have such feature, which is a bit sad because I now must look on workarounds (such issues are a result of human error and in big teams, it's unavoidable).

Comment: I have to admit, I was hoping `git diff -w` might have ignored the BOM. You are right, there ought to be an easy way to ask for it to be ignored. I think the difference you're seeing comes from the history of use of BOMs. On Windows, many tools insert it automatically, including Microsoft tools, so it would have been obvious for the authors of WinMerge that it had to be handled, while Git comes from the Linux universe, where I believe BOMs have been much more rarely used (because we went mostly straight to utf-8, for which the BOM is not useful).